# "tlsv1 alert unknown ca" in node.js

Tags: node.js, openssl

For the last 5 days I've got a lot of weird errors in my app's logs. Here is the stack trace:

```
Error: 140428615087936:error:14094418:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert unknown ca:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s3_pkt.c:1234:SSL alert number 48 
  at CleartextStream._pusher (tls.js:674:24) 
  at SlabBuffer.use (tls.js:217:18) 
  at CleartextStream.CryptoStream._push (tls.js:501:33) 
  at SecurePair.cycle (tls.js:898:20) 
  at EncryptedStream.CryptoStream.write (tls.js:285:13) 
  at Socket.ondata (stream.js:38:26) 
  at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96:17) 
  at TCP.onread (net.js:397:14)
```

It is the same for all these errors. Node.js version is 0.8.24. 
Does anybody know why it could happen?

Comment: If you have to stay on v0.8, did you try upgrading to v0.8.28 at least?

Comment: @mscdex that's a good idea. I gonna try to upgrade node to v0.8.28.

Comment: Please provide the relevant code *and* the server which you are connecting so we can test the server configuration.

Comment: @jww Sorry, but I can't give more details.

Comment: @schfkt - that could mean the question should be closed as *Unable to duplicate*. I say *"could"* because the community has to do it. If the community decides not to act on the question due to the missing information, then you may get an answer. (Nothing personal. Just giving you the possible outcomes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've solved that problem. It happened because of minor misconfiguration in SSL certificates on our other API server (which node.js talked to).

To check your SSL configuration you can use [one service](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) by SSL Labs. In our case there was this warning (incomplete chain issues):

[image: problem with SSL certificate chain]

To fix it you should do the following (excerpt from [nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#chains)):

> Some browsers may complain about a certificate signed by a well-known
>   certificate authority, while other browsers may accept the certificate
>   without issues. This occurs because the issuing authority has signed
>   the server certificate using an intermediate certificate that is not
>   present in the certificate base of well-known trusted certificate
>   authorities which is distributed with a particular browser. In this
>   case the authority provides a bundle of chained certificates which
>   should be concatenated to the signed server certificate. The server
>   certificate must appear before the chained certificates in the
>   combined file:
>
> ```
> $ cat www.example.com.crt bundle.crt > www.example.com.chained.crt
> ```
>
> The resulting file should be used in the ssl_certificate directive:
>
> ```
> server {
>     listen              443 ssl;
>     server_name         www.example.com;
>     ssl_certificate     www.example.com.chained.crt;
>     ssl_certificate_key www.example.com.key;
>     ...
> }
> ```

The key part is concatenation of certificate files. Errors in node.js app disappeared just after we've made that changes.